# Rails Controllers tests are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, devise

I am trying to do my first tests on rails but I am having troubles with it.
I am trying just to test one controller to understand how it works but it doesn't work.
I added the Devise helper to avoid problems with it but I still getting many errors.
I really appreciate so much any kind of help.

Here is the code of the Test Controller:

reportes_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ReportesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
include Devise::TestHelpers
  setup do
    @reporte = reportes(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:reportes)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create report" do
    assert_difference('Reporte.count') do
      post :create, reporte: { asignacion_actividad_id: @reporte.asignacion_actividad_id, descripcion: @reporte.descripcion}
    end

    assert_redirected_to reporte_path(assigns(:reporte))
  end

  test "should show report" do
    get :show, id: @reporte
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @reporte
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update report" do
    patch :update, id: @reporte, reporte: { asignacion_actividad_id: @reporte.asignacion_actividad_id, descripcion: @reporte.descripcion}
    assert_redirected_to reporte_path(assigns(:reporte))
  end

  test "should destroy report" do
    assert_difference('Reporte.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @reporte
    end

    assert_redirected_to reportes_path
  end
end
```

Here is the code of the Controller:
reportes_controller.rb

```
class ReportesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reporte, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
# asd
  #
  # GET /reportes
  # GET /reportes.json
  def index
        authorize! :index, Reporte
      @asignacion_actividades = AsignacionActividad.find_by(actividad_id: params[:actividad_id])
      @actividad = @asignacion_actividades.actividad 
          @proyecto = @actividad.proyecto
      @reportes_mios = []
      @asignacion_actividades.to_a.each do |asignacion|
        if asignacion.usuario == current_usuario && !asignacion.reportes.nil?
                @reportes_mios = @reportes_mios + asignacion.reportes
            end
      end
      @reportes_todos = @actividad.reportes

      @reportes_todos = [] if @reportes_todos.nil?
      @reportes_mios = [] if @reportes_mios.nil?
      @reportes_todos = @reportes_todos.uniq
      @reportes_mios = @reportes_mios.uniq
  end

  # GET /reportes/1
  # GET /reportes/1.json
  def show
        authorize! :show, Reporte
  end

  # GET /reportes/new
  def new
        authorize! :new, Reporte
    @actividad = Actividad.find(params[:actividad_id])
    @proyecto = @actividad.proyecto
    @asignacion_actividad = @actividad.asignacion_actividades.where('vigente =? and usuario_id =?', 'true' , current_usuario.id).uniq.last
    @asignacion_actividad_id = @asignacion_actividad.id
    @reporte = Reporte.new
  end

  # GET /reportes/1/edit
  def edit
        authorize! :edit, Reporte
  end

  # POST /reportes
  # POST /reportes.json
  def create
        authorize! :create, Reporte
    @reporte = Reporte.new(reporte_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reporte.save
          format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index', :actividad_id => @reporte.asignacion_actividad.actividad.id 
             flash[:notice] = 'Reporte was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reporte }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @reporte.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reportes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reportes/1.json
  def update
        authorize! :update, Reporte
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reporte.update(reporte_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @reporte, notice: 'Reporte was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reporte }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @reporte.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reportes/1
  # DELETE /reportes/1.json
  def destroy
        authorize! :destroy, Reporte
    @reporte.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reportes_url, notice: 'Reporte was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_reporte
      @reporte = Reporte.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def reporte_params
      params.require(:reporte).permit(:descripcion, :asignacion_actividad_id)
    end
end
```

And here is the error that I get when i try to execute it:
rake test TEST=test/controllers/reportes_controller_test.rb

```
Run options: --seed 7969

# Running:

FFFFFFE

Finished in 0.540113s, 12.9603 runs/s, 11.1088 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
ReportesControllerTest#test_should_create_report [/home/blackswan/proyectoFinal/SEVU/test/controllers/reportes_controller_test.rb:21]:
"Reporte.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2


  2) Failure:
ReportesControllerTest#test_should_destroy_report [/home/blackswan/proyectoFinal/SEVU/test/controllers/reportes_controller_test.rb:44]:
"Reporte.count" didn't change by -1.
Expected: 1
  Actual: 2


  3) Failure:
ReportesControllerTest#test_should_get_edit [/home/blackswan/proyectoFinal/SEVU/test/controllers/reportes_controller_test.rb:35]:
Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>


  4) Failure:
ReportesControllerTest#test_should_get_index [/home/blackswan/proyectoFinal/SEVU/test/controllers/reportes_controller_test.rb:11]:
Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>


  5) Failure:
ReportesControllerTest#test_should_get_new [/home/blackswan/proyectoFinal/SEVU/test/controllers/reportes_controller_test.rb:17]:
Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>


  6) Failure:
ReportesControllerTest#test_should_show_report [/home/blackswan/proyectoFinal/SEVU/test/controllers/reportes_controller_test.rb:30]:
Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>


  7) Error:
ReportesControllerTest#test_should_update_report:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"reportes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
    test/controllers/reportes_controller_test.rb:40:in `block in <class:ReportesControllerTest>'

7 runs, 6 assertions, 6 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

What can i do? If i solve this error I will be able to test all the controllers.
I will appreaciate any answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it about authorization, is your controller works well?

If you don't mind, you can take a look on [RedMine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Download), it has many test case to refer.

Comment: I check all about authorization but it seems all ok. What more could it be?